# Three js Shader Material - Pixelated glitching when transparency is set to true

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl

I'm playing around with shaders for the first time and using THREE.RawShaderMaterial on a few meshes.
I'm getting some strange artifacts on my very simple shaders:

Vertex shader:

```
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;

uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec4 color;

varying vec3 vPosition;

void main() {
    vPosition = position;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;

varying vec3 vPosition;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor.r = vPosition.x;
    gl_FragColor.g = vPosition.y;
    gl_FragColor.b = 1.0;
}
```

which I use on a whole bunch of objects which are created like so:

```
asdfobject = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add(asdfobject);

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 4, 4);
var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({

    uniforms: {
        time: { type: "f", value: 1.0 }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    transparent: true,
} );

for(var i = 0; i < 80; i++) {

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5, Math.random() - 0.5);
    mesh.position.multiplyScalar(400);
    mesh.rotation.set(Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 2, Math.random() * 2);
    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = Math.random() * 50;
    asdfobject.add(mesh);

}
```

The colour on the objects should be completely smooth, but sometimes they look a bit "glitchy" and pixelated like shown in this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/weqqv5z5/
This happens especially when resizing the window.

I cannot figure out why this happens, I just know that the effect does not happen when `transparent` in the material is set to false (on line 23 in the fiddle)

I haven't been able to test this on any other devices yet, so it may be a graphics card specific problem, too. I am running a 64-bit Arch Linux laptop with Intel HD 4000 graphics.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the alpha value of your fragment color.

```
gl_FragColor.a = 0.5;
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/weqqv5z5/1/

three.js r.71

Comment: Thanks so much! I had only tried changing the opacity in the material to various values, but changing the opacity value in the shader makes more sense.